# Xdebug PHPStorm IDE ubuntu

Tags: php, xdebug, phpstorm

I am trying to configure xDebug with phpstorm 2.1 on ubuntu 11.04
In phpstorm I clicked "Start Listen PHP DEBUG CONNECTIONS" and "xdebug Start session" firefox  bookmarklet from here http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/. 
But nothing doesn't happen.

```
PHP 5.3:
extension="xdebug.so" (not zend)

[xdebug]
xdebug.idekey = "PHPSTORM"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xbebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

I broke my brains why it doesn't work. Need advices. Very thanks

**UPD SOLVED: XDEBUG should be installed as zend extension!**

Answer (score 1):

Please check you phpinfo() output - it should contain 'Xdebug' section. See [Xdebug installation guide](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/WI/Xdebug+installation+guide)

Does Xdebug installed correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the tutorial here: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/webide/2011/02/zero-configuration-debugging-with-xdebug-and-phpstorm-2-0/.

You could also take a look at the KomodoIDE remote debugging instructions and see if they help you out: http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/6.1/debugphp.html#debugphp_top.

Comment: Can you telnet to your remote server on port 9000?

Comment: telnet 127.0.0.1:9000
telnet: could not resolve 127.0.0.1:9000/telnet: Name or service not known

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is a the local server. You need to telnet from your workstation to your remote server on port 9000